# Ошибка. Страница перестала отвечать на запросы. А она работает нормально

Tags: javascript, joomla3, fabricjs

Моя страница отлично работает, ну вот нет никакого намека на зависание или ошибку в консоли. Весь функционал работает, но через каждые 10-15 минут сайт на Joomla 3.0, js и fabric js выстреливает сообщение - Следующая страница перестала отвечать на запросы. И ведь продолжает работать без тормозов и запинок.

Моих знаний не хватило, чтобы отследить ощутимые потери в памяти через инструменты разработчика google.

Может быть кто-то сталкивался с подобным и подскажет в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проверка оптимизированности JS скриптов:

```
chrome -> developer tools -> Perfomance -> Record -> Stop -> Call Tree
```

отсортировать по `Self Time`, потом по `Total Time`
и посмотреть какие функции долгое время занимают / грузят страницу и проверить почему.

Comment: Супер. Спасибо огромное. Пошел разбираться.